# How to add CSS to the foreach result in CodeIgniter view?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, foreach

Here I got some data from table cart using foreach. Now I want to display as like below (with heading and value as like in the table):

[image]

controller

```
   $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id,username,useremail FROM tbl_cart');

   $resultdata['results'] = $query->result_array(); 

$this->load->view('one/home_comman_page/head');
$this->load->view('one/usercart', $resultdata);
$this->load->view('one/home_comman_page/footer');
$this->load->view('one/home_comman_page/script');
}else{

        redirect('users/login');
    }
}
```

view

```
<?php

 foreach($results as $result)
 {

echo '<span>'.$result['id'].'</span>';echo'</br>';
echo '<span>'.$result['useremail'].'</span>';echo'</br>';
echo '<span>'.$result['username'].'</span>';echo'</br>';


}
```

How can I display the foreach result data as like the db table?

Comment: You're using `<span>` tags which are **inline elements**. That means that they'll sit next to each other on the page. You may want to swap to a table structure, using `<td>` tags :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the HTML table tags.

```
<table>
  <?php foreach($results as $result)
  {
    echo '<tr style="border:1px solid grey;">';
    echo '<td>.$result['id'].</td>';
    echo '<td>.$result['useremail'].</td>';
    echo '<td>.$result['username'].</td></tr>';

  } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: `tr` should be inside `for` loop else all the data will display in one line i.e in one `tr`

Answer (score 2):

Try using a table, you are doing it wrong

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>User Email</td>
    <td>Username</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($results as $result) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['useremail']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['username']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<table class='table_Class' >";
foreach($results as $result)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$result['id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$result['useremail']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$result['username']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Good catch. The award definitely goes to Amila. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** you need to embed the record set into html `table` like below

**2nd :** Read basic html table tag here [refer here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

```
<table border="1px">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>S.no</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>UserName</th>
    .......
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($results as $result) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['user_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['username']; ?></td>
        ......
    </tr>

    <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>User Email</th>
   </tr>
 <?php foreach($results as $result) {?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['username']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['useremail']; ?></td>
  </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Also you can add some style like:

```
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
```